# Unity Facebook SDK Graph request for uploading screenshot returns 403: Forbidden

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I'm using `Facebook SDK for Unity v7.1.0`. My goal is to complete graph request that posts screenshot to user's feed. For testing purpose I use facebook examples in Unity, but as you see in this image nobody can post screenshot but me.

[image]

It says `403: Forbidden` when somebody else tries to post image, but fun part is just beginning. Another user that tests the program is already an administrator on Facebook app page. Also Facebook app is already live and public. I've submitted publish_actions permission and it is enabled as you see in this screenshot.

[image]

Key Hash from keystore is added to Facebook app and APK is signed. I found some similar issues and tried to apply some fixes, but nothing worked for me.

Any comment will be appreciated please help!

Comment: Have you tried checking access tokens? If other users have not granted permissions it would not work.

Comment: Thank you for response, but after a day it started working. No idea why, and what was the problem. Access tokens was ok, and then i've published  the app. So no tokens needed but token from keystore.